# jQuery ui loads before jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui

I have a rails project that uses the jquery-ui slider widget.

My problem is that the jquery-ui widgets only appear if I reload the page. The first time the page loads the widget doesn't appear. If I press f5, it does.

I think the problem that jquery-ui is loading before jquery, but I have it in the correct order in my application.js.

This happens in chrome and firefox too.

Thanks in advance for your answers and your time.

Comment: If the `<script>` tags are in the wrong order, a quick "view source" would show that. You would also see errors in the console. Have you checked?

Comment: Indeed it's in the right order:
`
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1"></script>

<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1"></script>

<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/bootstrap.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/application.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery.ui.core.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery.ui.all.js?body=1"></script>`

Comment: Have you checked for errors in the browser console?

Comment: ok, solved! The problem is that I was including several times the same javascript files. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

ok, solved! The problem is that I was including several times the same javascript files. Thanks everyone!